# How to find the area of a segment of a circle if we know the radius and an angle?

Tags: c++, geometry, formula

I have some problems to find an area of a segment of a circle.

[image: Formula circle segment area]

I try to use this formula but have another result, as here http://planetcalc.com/1421/ , i use calculator circle segment area to check my result from terminal.

my code:

```
#define PI 3.14159265

double r = 12;
double a = 22;
double result = ((r*r)/2)*(PI*(a/180)-sin(a));
```

Comment: _"I have some problems ..."_ You forgot to tell us what these are specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your `sin` calculations a bit, it should look like this:

```
sin(M_PI * angle / 180)
```

Comment: He was not converting properly, he used wrong value to calculate sine.